# Setting up hMailServer SMTP on port 2525

Tags: email, smtp, windows-server-2008, mail-server, hmail-server

I currently have a working hmailserver on a windows server 2008 vps. My server currently listens on port 25 as usual. Since a couple of days now I've been having problems sending e-mails from hotels and weird isps that block port 25. I've solved this issue on non-vps servers by making my smtp listen on port 2525 as well.

The problem is that I don't really know how to make hmailserver to listen on port 2525. I've browsed the hmailserveradministrator options and searched on google but I can't find anything related on the subject.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can make hMailServer listen on two ports at the same time.

Settings > Advanced > TCP/IP Ports >

SMTP, 0.0.0.0, 25

SMTP, 0.0.0.0, 2525